# Do I need to install active directory on am RDS terminal server?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, terminal-server, rds

I am trying to configure a test RDS terminal Windows Server 2012 as a member server to domain controller 2012 that has active directory installed and running on the domain controller.

Do I need to have active directory installed on the RDS terminal sever too?

If I do need active directory installed on the RDS terminal server 2012, is there a way I can copy the active directory from the domain controller on to the RDS terminal server?

Answer (score 2):

If you DID install a second, or third, or however many more domain controllers they would all be "copies" of the first domain controller. This is how Active Directory works. All servers are replicated, and changes on one propagate to all the others.

While you could install active directory on your RDS server, you do not need to. And, more importantly, you should NEVER do that for security reasons.